# AChartEngine: Help needing with axis labels

Tags: java, android, achartengine

I am using the AChartEngine (I think it's pretty cool!) to display two series to compare their daily values. Unfortunately, there are some issues I cannot solve and even if I have searched this site, I haven't been able to find the solution. It would be great if someone could give me a hand.

If you look at the screenshot, you see that the x-axis has two "label axis". One is the right one displaying the dates, the other one consists of intergers, starting from 0 until 8. I would like to remove these integers.

Second, The chart can be moved around. As I am always displaying the data part interesting, I have no need to do so and I would like to disable this feature.

This is my configuration code:

```
    public XYMultipleSeriesRenderer getBarChartRenderer() {
    XYMultipleSeriesRenderer renderer = new XYMultipleSeriesRenderer();
    renderer.setAxisTitleTextSize(20);
    renderer.setChartTitleTextSize(18);
    renderer.setLabelsTextSize(18);
    renderer.setLegendTextSize(18);
    //renderer.setMargins(new int[]{20, 30, 15, 0});
    SimpleSeriesRenderer r = new SimpleSeriesRenderer();
    r.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
    renderer.addSeriesRenderer(r);
    r = new SimpleSeriesRenderer();
    r.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    renderer.addSeriesRenderer(r);
    return renderer;
}

private void setBarChartSettings(XYMultipleSeriesRenderer renderer, String sTitle, String sXAxisTitle, String sYAxisTitle, String[] aDates) {
    renderer.setChartTitle(sTitle);
    renderer.setXTitle(sXAxisTitle);
    renderer.setYTitle(sYAxisTitle);
    renderer.setXAxisMin(0);
    renderer.setXAxisMax(aDates.length + 1);
    renderer.setYAxisMin(0);
    renderer.setYAxisMax(40);
    renderer.setShowGridY(true);
    renderer.setShowGridX(true);
    renderer.setGridColor(Color.WHITE);
    renderer.setXLabelsColor(Color.WHITE);
    renderer.setYLabelsColor(0, Color.WHITE);
    renderer.setXLabelsAlign(Paint.Align.CENTER);
    renderer.setYLabelsAlign(Paint.Align.RIGHT);

    for (int i = 0; i < aDates.length; i++) {
        renderer.addXTextLabel(i + 1, aDates[i]);
    }
    //renderer.setXLabelsAngle(-30.0f);
    renderer.setXLabelsAlign(Paint.Align.CENTER);
    renderer.setXLabelsPadding(10);
}
```

Thanks!

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you need to disable the default numerical labels:

```
renderer.setXLabels(0);
```

And you also need to disable the pan and zoom operations:

```
renderer.setPanEnabled(false, false);
renderer.setZoomEnabled(false, false);
```

Comment: Hi Dan, this helped in the case that the additional labels are gone. What's still missing is that the labels are in the middle of two bars. Basically, the date label corresponds to a pair of bars and therefore I would like their ticks to be between both bars. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

OK, that's my solution:

```
    renderer.setChartTitle(sTitle);
    renderer.setXTitle(sXAxisTitle);
    renderer.setYTitle(sYAxisTitle);
    renderer.setXAxisMin(0);
    renderer.setXAxisMax(aDates.length);
    renderer.setYAxisMin(0);
    renderer.setYAxisMax(40);

    renderer.setXLabels(0);

    renderer.setPanEnabled(false, false);
    renderer.setZoomEnabled(false, false);

    renderer.setShowGridY(true);
    renderer.setShowGridX(true);
    renderer.setGridColor(Color.WHITE);
    renderer.setXLabelsColor(Color.WHITE);
    renderer.setYLabelsColor(0, Color.WHITE);
    renderer.setXLabelsAlign(Paint.Align.CENTER);
    renderer.setYLabelsAlign(Paint.Align.RIGHT);

    renderer.addXTextLabel(0, "");
    for (int i = 0; i < aDates.length; i++) {
        renderer.addXTextLabel(i + 1, aDates[i]);
    }
    renderer.setXLabelsAlign(Paint.Align.CENTER);
    renderer.setXLabelsPadding(10);
    renderer.setYLabelsPadding(10);
```

Now, the chart is displayed as I wish it to be.